# How do I permanently avoid an update?

Tags: updates, package-management, unity-2d

I have noted after installing the first huge block of updates you get after a fresh installation, Unity 3D would disappear leaving me only 2D support. So, not exactly knowing what did that depend on, I chose to deselect all Unity-2D updates from the list. The problem is, every time new updates are introduced, that ones I'm desperately trying to avoid are always showing up. That's for me annoying, as I have to manually deselect them all the times, and dangerous, as every time I risk installing them and find everything screwed up.

Now, is there a way to tell update manager to forget about those packages unless I expressly request them? Or at least to make him show them already deselected among all others?

Is it sufficiently trying to hold them? I mean, some may be new packages, instead of already existing packages that are being brought to a newer version. If someone can tell me also which packages the 2D depend on, so that I can install other maybe useful packages, that's even better.

The ones I deselected are: `libunity-2d-private0`, `unity-2d`, `unity-2d-common`, `unity-2d-panel`, `unity-2d-shell`, `unity-2d-spread`.

Comment: You can a package management front-end called "muon". It has convenient update system, i.e if you deselect a package like unity-2d all dependent packages of it is deselected. i believe, it is written in qt

Comment: Thanks! If I got it right, Muon is an alternative to Synaptic which can fulfill Update Manager's job too, is it? To use it, do I have to install it and tell Update Manager to never check for updates, like Ketan Patel said, to disable it and have only Muon working? Or can I directly remove the old Manager?

Comment: Update: looking in the software center I found three separate Muon programs: a Software Center, a Package Manager and an Update Manager. Can I install the last one alone? Or do you think Muon is still better than the default Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic? In the description of Software Center I read it is mainly for KDE, will the Update Manager work good in Unity?

Comment: Yes, Muon is for KDE. but Should work or Unity too. choosing only the Update Manager will do the job. Also, I think, you have to manually check for updates using muon updater

Comment: I installed it, but can't understand at all if I can actually permanently exclude an update...

Comment: I said, with this tool, you can select which package to update. Slightly different,but you can first select to update all and then exclude unity-2d from update.

Answer (score 2):

Go in system settings> Software Updates. 
Unchecked all options. Select Never check updates.

Comment: He wanted to have updates. Only wanted to disable unity-2d updates